# Change color of PNG background (transparent to color)

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor

I need to change the background color of a PNG to a specific color.
The background of the lable renders black and I want so set the color by my own.

How can I do it within the node editor?

[image: Preview render]

Here's the PNG and the nodes:

[image: PNG]

[image: Nodes]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just add in a *MixRGB* node between your transparent image and the color of the principled shader.

Make sure you plug in the alpha socket into the factor of the *MixRGB* node and change the color to your liking.

[image: animated gif - color changing]

[image: cycles material nodes]

Comment: O was trying it earlier  with mix RGB and some other Nodes but never had figuered it out, i was close but now it works.

Comment: So connecting the Alpha Channel to the Fac Input tells wich part to seperate from each other and the order of the Color inputs which part to colorize?! Hope thats right. If yes, i understand the hole process now.
Thanks for the solution!

Comment: You're absolutely correct!

Comment: It's easier if you don't think in terms of transparency, but how to use a mask to control how two colors or shader mix together. Read [Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447)