# How to make Image Texture have white background and/or transparent background with a second white material behind it on the same object?

Tags: uv, image

I have a creature in Blender that I'm trying to texture the eye of. Right now the eye is a sphere with an Image Texture Material on it. The Image Texture is a .png of a pupil with a transparent background. When I put that as an Image Texture on a material, it shows up with a Black background. But I want the creature to have a white eye behind the pupil.

How do I toggle with the settings to achieve a White background behind the transparent-background pupil texture png? I can attach pictures of my setup if needed but I've barely touched the default settings.

Thank you.

Edit: Solved! Submitted answer below.

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material

Comment: Thank you!  That helped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change color of PNG background (transparent to color)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112059/change-color-of-png-background-transparent-to-color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer helped me the most: [Change color of PNG background (transparent to color)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112059/change-color-of-png-background-transparent-to-color)

Particularly using the MixRBG for Nodes (which btw are in 'Shader' window, not 'Nodes' window)

I copied the MixRBG part of this guy's setup. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZOHk.jpg

Thanks all!